# Django DRF with oAuth2 using DOT (django-oauth-toolkit)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make DRF work with oAuth2 (django-oauth-toolkit).

I was focusing on http://httplambda.com/a-rest-api-with-django-and-oauthw-authentication/

First I followed that instruction, but later, after getting authentication errors, I setup this demo: https://github.com/felix-d/Django-Oauth-Toolkit-Python-Social-Auth-Integration

Result was the same: I couldn't generate access token using this curl:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" -u "<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/
```

I got this error:

```
{"error": "unsupported_grant_type"}
```

The oAuth2 application was set with grant_type password. I changed grant_type to "client credentials" and tried this curl:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -u "<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/
```

This worked and I got generated auth token.

After that I tried to get a list of all beers:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <auth_token>" http://127.0.0.1:8000/beers/
```

And I got this response:

```
{"detail":"You do not have permission to perform this action."}
```

This is the content of **views.py** that should show the beers:

```
from beers.models import Beer
from beers.serializer import BeerSerializer
from rest_framework import generics, permissions

class BeerList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BeerSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Beer.objects.filter(owner=user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

I am not sure what can be the problem here. First with "unsuported grant type" and later with other curl call. This also happen to me when I did basic tutorial from django-oauth-toolkit. I am using Django 1.8.2 and python3.4

Thanks for all help!

My settings.py looks like this

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = 'hd#x!ysy@y+^*%i+klb)o0by!bh&7nu3uhg+5r0m=$3x$a!j@9'

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'oauth2_provider',
    'rest_framework',
    'beers',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'beerstash.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'beerstash.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    )
}

OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    # this is the list of available scopes
    'SCOPES': {'read': 'Read scope', 'write': 'Write scope'}
}
```

Comment: what does your settings look like?  have you added all the settings for oauth to be used as REST Framework API authentication?

Comment: @AlexT I added my settings.py file

Comment: newer version uses : `from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import OAuth2Authentication`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have tried the demo you mentioned and everything was fine.

```
$ curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=superuser&assword=123qwe" -u"xLJuHBcdgJHNuahvER9pgqSf6vcrlbkhCr75hTCZ:nv9gzOj0BMf2cdxoxsnYZuRYTK5QwpKWiZc7USuJpm11DNtSE9X6Ob9KaVTKaQqeyQZh4KF3oZS4IJ7o9n4amzfqKJnoL7a2tYQiWgtYPSQpY6VKFjEazcqSacqTx9z8" http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/
{"access_token": "jlLpKwzReB6maEnjuJrk2HxE4RHbiA", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 36000, "refresh_token": "DsDWz1LiSZ3bd7NVuLIp7Dkj6pbse1", "scope": "read write groups"}
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer jlLpKwzReB6maEnjuJrk2HxE4RHbiA" http://127.0.0.1:8000/beers/
[]
```

In your case, I think, you have created an application with wrong *"Authorization grant type"*.

Use this application settings:

```
Name: just a name of your choice
Client Type: confidential
Authorization Grant Type: Resource owner password-based
```

This https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-3-register-an-application helped me a lot.

Here the database file I've created: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxeyphkiy141i1l/db.sqlite3.tar.gz?dl=0

You can try it yourself. No source code changed at all.
Django admin username - superuser, password -  123qwe.

Comment: I tested it again - with settings as you said and it was working! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4):

When you use "client credentials" it doesn't set the user on the generated access token, this is the root of that `you do not have permission` error you are seeing.

When using the `client credentials` grant type, you need to set the Rest Framework permission handler to look at tokens as `client credentials` does not set the user on the generated token. Django OAuth Toolkit provides custom permissions for this purpose:

https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rest-framework/permissions.html

Or if your entire API is subject to the same type of permissions you can just set the permission handler globally in your `settings.py`file, for example:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.TokenHasReadWriteScope',
    )
}
```

This assumes of course that you grant `read write` permissions at the time.

More info about scopes here:

https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html

Comment: For more recent version of replace 'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication' with  'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication' and 'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.TokenHasReadWriteScope' with 'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.TokenHasReadWriteScope',